# AWS-SDK for node js connection management

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Does aws-sdk for node js manage it's connections through an internal pool?

Their documentation kind of leads me to believe that.

> httpOptions (map) — A set of options to pass to the low-level HTTP
>   request. Currently supported options are:
>
> proxy [String] — the URL to proxy requests through agent [http.Agent,
>   https.Agent] — the Agent object to perform HTTP requests with. Used
>   for connection pooling. Defaults to the global agent
>   (http.globalAgent) for non-SSL connections. Note that for SSL
>   connections, a special Agent object is used in order to enable peer
>   certificate verification. This feature is only available in the
>   Node.js environment.

But there's no way, at least none that I could find, that'd let me define any connection pool properties.

What are my options if I want to control the concurrent connections in use?

Is it better to let the SDK handle that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can give the [http.Agent](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) with whatever settings you want for max sockets.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var http = require('http');
AWS.config.update({
  httpOptions: {
    agent: new http.Agent(...)
  }
})
```

Comment: But isn't the SDK using a different custom agent for https?

Comment: see a similar code example in the docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-configuring.html#Registering_Certificate_Bundles

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking into this a little bit more.

I dug around and figured out the defaults being used.

AWS-SDK is using the node `http` module, of which the `defaultSocketCount` is `INFINITY`.

They are using `https` module under the wraps with a `maxSocketCount` of `50`.

The relevant code snippet.

```
sslAgent: function sslAgent() {
    var https = require('https');

    if (!AWS.NodeHttpClient.sslAgent) {
      AWS.NodeHttpClient.sslAgent = new https.Agent({rejectUnauthorized: true});
      AWS.NodeHttpClient.sslAgent.setMaxListeners(0);

      // delegate maxSockets to globalAgent, set a default limit of 50 if current value is Infinity.
      // Users can bypass this default by supplying their own Agent as part of SDK configuration.
      Object.defineProperty(AWS.NodeHttpClient.sslAgent, 'maxSockets', {
        enumerable: true,
        get: function() {
          var defaultMaxSockets = 50;
          var globalAgent = https.globalAgent;
          if (globalAgent && globalAgent.maxSockets !== Infinity && typeof globalAgent.maxSockets === 'number') {
            return globalAgent.maxSockets;
          }
          return defaultMaxSockets;
        }
      });
    }
    return AWS.NodeHttpClient.sslAgent;
  }
```

For manipulating the socket counts, see BretzL's answer.

There is however now way to set the agent for both `http` and `https` at once. You can work around this by updating the configuration as you switch from `http` to `https` and vice versa.

See : https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1185